# Add body class to Node Display (to distinguish it from Node/Edit or Node/add view)

Tags: theming

I want to add a body class that will only appear on the *actual node display* (e.g. `mysite.com/node/1`). I don't want this body class to appear on the node/edit page (e.g. (`mysite.com/node/1/edit`) or the node/add page.

The reason for this is that I am making custom node form templates. At the moment, the css gets wrongly applied to the node Display.

I know I could just add a wrapper DIV to my templates, but I would rather use the body class, as it will be more efficient for my theming work flow.

I have successfully applied body classes to the *edit* and *add* displays with the following code in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ((arg(0)=='node' && arg(2)=='edit') || (arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-edit-page';
  }
}
```

Is there something similar I could use to target the actual node display? I tried doing a KPR dump of the page, node and HTML hooks with theme_devel, but I could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arg(2) will return NULL on node pages (like node/1).

```
  if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-view-page';
  }
```